# How to find the difference between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

How can I find the difference between two dates.  For example, the difference between a birthdate and the current date. Both dates would be in text boxes.

Comment: This is a pretty basic question, and it was very poorly worded.  I think we generally expect a little more from a question being asked here.  Also, it might benefit you to learn about and use the MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx

Comment: Really - this question got up-voted?  I guess this is what "sympathy voting" is...

Answer (score 1):

I'll simply assume a text box named BirthdateTextBox exists and contains your birth date:

```
DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Parse(BirthdateTextBox.Text);
TimeSpan timeBetweenDates = DateTime.Now.Subtract(birthDate);
```

There are also some overloads of DateTime.Parse, as well as DateTime.TryParse, that you should [read about in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert the string obtained from text box to `DateTime` format.

   DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBoxStringOne);

   DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBoxStringTwo);
2. Compute the difference

   System.TimeSpan difference = dt1.Subtract(d2); // Assuming dt1 > dt2

Hope, this should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

look into the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) class, it supports subtracting two dates, which will result in a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

You can create a `DateTime` object from a string by using its `Parse()` or [`ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) methods, there are plenty of examples on how to use these here on SO or on msdn - it depends on the format of your time string.

Answer (score -2):

You can use
`DATEDIFF (datepart ,startdate ,enddate )`

1.datepart- difference in yr,month
2. startDate
3. enddate

2 and 3 are DateTime objects

DateTime.Now will get currentDate

[Read more for DateDiff()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about a database being involved.

Comment: question is tagged for C# and asp.net not T-SQL